# elasticsearch update query

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Create a document/table 'task' in ElasticSearch with the following fields

- ID (Auto generated while inserting)
- task_id (Integer)
- priority (integer)
- queue (varchar)
- process (varchar)
- task (varchar)
- status (char)
- user (char)
- description (varchar)
- due_date (Date Time)
- created_on (Date time)
- updated_on (Date time)

Comment: to create mappings you also need to think about your search usecases so as to select proper analyzers and indexing options on each field

Comment: im new for this elasticsearch i don't know much

Comment: POST /mytask/my
{
 - "ID" : "integer"
-"task_id" :"Integer"
"priority" : "integer"
"queue" :"varchar"
-"process" :"varchar"
-"task" :"varchar"
-"status" :"char"
-"user" :"char"
-"description" :"varchar"
-"due_date" :"Date"
-"created_on" :"Date"
-"updated_on" :"Date"
}"error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are couple commands which will help you to set-up basic ES index:

1. Set-up your mappings:

   ```
   curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/my_tasks -d '
   {
     "mappings": {
       "task": {
         "properties": {
           "task_id": {
             "type":     "integer"
           },
           "priority": {
             "type":     "integer"
           },
           "queue": {
             "type":     "string"
           },
           "process": {
             "type":     "string"
           },
           "task": {
             "type":     "string"
           },
           "status": {
             "type":     "string"
           },
           "user": {
             "type":     "string"
           },
           "description": {
             "type":     "string"
           },
           "due_date": {
             "type":     "date"
           },
           "created_on": {
             "type":     "date"
           },
           "updated_on": {
             "type":     "date"
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }'
   ```
2. Set-up simple document:

   ```
   curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/my_tasks/task/ -d '
   {
     "task_id": "64123",
     "priority": "2",
     "queue": "Implementation",
     "process": "Project Sample",
     "task": "Feature-64123",
     "status": "In Progress",
     "user": "John Smith",
     "description": "Set-up basic ElasticSearch task",
     "due_date": "2017-03-24T00:00:00Z",
     "created_on": "2017-03-21T01:51:12Z",
     "updated_on": "2017-03-21T01:56:54Z"
   }'
   ```
3. Query your index (silly `match_all` query):

   ```
   curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_tasks/_search -d '
   {
       "query": {
           "match_all": {}
       }
   }'
   ```